# Problem with orders and product orders laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade, orders

Good evening, I have an orders and orders_products table:
A supplier (user) can upload products to sell them.

If buyer buys a product from different suppliers. That he has for example 3 products buy from different supplier, I want to separate.

For each product purchased from different suppliers it will represent an order for the buyer made by the buyer.

I made my code for the order but I can't seem to place an order for each supplier, please I really need help.

This is my PHP code:

```
public function validation_commande(Request $request){
        $utilisateur = Utilisateur::where('id','=',session('utilisateur'))->first();
        $paniers = Panier::where('utilisateur_id','=',$utilisateur->id)->get();
        $utilisateur_id = $utilisateur->id;
        $mode_paiement_id = 4;
        $adresse = Adresse::where('utilisateur_id','=',$utilisateur_id)
        ->where('adresse_par_defaut','=',1)
        ->first();
        $total_ht = 0;
        $total_ttc = 0;
        $nombre_produit_panier = count($paniers);
        if($nombre_produit_panier >= 1)
        {
            foreach ($paniers as $c) {
                    $total_ht += $c->produit->prix_total($c->quantite);
                    $total_ttc += $c->produit->prix_total_ttc($c->quantite);
                    $commande = Commande::firstOrCreate([
                        'utilisateur_id'=>$utilisateur_id,
                        'fournisseur_id'=>$c->produit->utilisateur_id,
                        'boutique_id'=>$c->produit->boutique_id,
                        'statut'=>'en_cours_de_traitement',
                        'statut_fournisseur'=>'pas_encore_vue_sa_commande',
                        'total_ht'=>$total_ht,
                        'total_ttc'=>$total_ttc,
                        'mode_paiement_id'=>$mode_paiement_id,
                        'adresse_id'=>$adresse->id,
                        'date_commande'=>now()
                    ]);
                    break;            }
            if($c->achat_groupe == 1){
                $achat_groupe = 1;
            }else{
                $achat_groupe = 0;
            }
            foreach ($paniers as $c) {
                CommandeProduit::create([
                    'commande_id'=>$commande->id,
                    'produit_id'=>$c->produit->id,
                    'prix_ht'=>$c->produit->prix_sans_taxe($c->quantite),
                    'prix_ttc'=>$c->produit->prix($c->quantite),
                    'quantite'=>$c->quantite,
                    'utilisateur_id'=>$utilisateur->id,
                    'fournisseur_id'=>$c->produit->utilisateur_id,
                    'boutique_id'=>$c->produit->boutique_id,
                    'achat_groupe'=>$achat_groupe,
                    'date_creation'=>now()
                ]);
            }
            $message_a_envoye = "**** Market Makers **** \n \n";
            $message_a_envoye .= "Une nouvelle commande vient d'arriver";
            // $date_du_jour = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
            // $message_a_envoye .= "Date d'inscription : ".$utilisateur->date_creation."\n";
            // $this->telegram_send(urlencode($message_a_envoye));
            // sleep(3);
            $this->telegram_send_2(urlencode($message_a_envoye));
            $lien_button = env('APP_URL').'/mes-commandes-b/';
            $data = [
                'subject' => "Nouvelle commande",
                'titre_page' => 'Vous avez reçu une nouvelle commande',
                'message' => 'Vous avez reçu une nouvelle commande sur votre espace Market Makers',
                'lien_button' => $lien_button,
                'message_button' => 'Voir'
            ];
            // Mail::to($c->produit->utilisateur->email)->send(new NotificationMail($data,$c->produit->utilisateur));
            Session::flash('success','Votre commande a bien été effectué avec succès');
            Panier::where('utilisateur_id', $utilisateur->id)->delete();
            $request->session()->put('venue_du_panier',null);
            return redirect(route('mes-commandes'));
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect(route('mes-commandes'));
        }
    }
```

http://pastebin.fr/96873

Comment: You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69670139/edit) if you want to add more details. Please identify if the issue is coming from PHP code or MySQL?

Comment: the code works correctly when the customer orders from the same supplier, but when he orders from several users we always have only one order whereas I want an order from each for different suppliers.

I would say the problem is with php